# How can i get the window viewport size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I tried to get the window viewport width. when i use **document.documentElement.clientHeight(or)window.innerWidth** i can get exactly what i need. If i logged In at minimize mode,then if i maximize the window the viewport width will not be resized.I got the viewport width when it is minimized. how can i slove it?
  I also tried to use **document.body.clientHeight**.But here also i got problem.The viewport size is larger than my viewport,because of statusbar.Then i subtract the statusbar size,then i got the viewport size.If i have anotherbar in my window again i got the same problem.
  Exactly what i need is how can get the end user viewport size?Please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dont forget you can also 'accept' answers- having 0% acceptance may deter some contributers from answering

Answer (score 4):

from the jQuery docs:

http://api.jquery.com/height/
http://api.jquery.com/width/

```
$(window).width();   // returns width of browser viewport
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
```

Comment: yes i tried this also but i got the same problem If i logged In at minimize mode,then if i maximize the window the viewport width will not be resized.

Comment: did you try something like `$(window).resize(function() { console.log($(window).width(); })` on Firebug?

Comment: this is in jQuery's resize() doc:  $(window).resize(function() {
  $('body').prepend('<div>' + $(window).width() + '</div>');
});

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$myviewport.getHeight();
$myviewport.getWidth();
```

Where myviewport is the viewport OBJECT. You can also use:

```
Ext.getCmp('myviewport').getHeight();
Ext.getCmp('myviewport').getWidth();
```

Where 'myviewport' is the ID of the viewport object.

Use

```
.getHeight(true);
.getWidth(true);
```

To get the height/width minus padding, margins, borders etc.

Comment: The above is aimed at an ExtJS implementation as per your tagging of the question

Answer (score 1):

As a consequence of the proliferation of different browsers' ideas about this, it's a surprisingly tricky thing to get right. David Mark (author of [My Library](http://www.cinsoft.net/mylib.html)) is particularly strong in this area and has written an article on the subject: http://www.cinsoft.net/viewport.asp